# How to find the perimeter of this shape

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

For DIY project, I need to calculate the perimeter (the blue line) of this shape - a circle resting on a middle of the line:

I know the radius of the circle (**r**) and the length of the line (**a**). If I remember correctly, **b** should be equal to *a / 2* (right?)

so, it gives me:

*p = 2a + c*

But how do I calculate the length of the arc (**c**) ?

I'd appreciate if someone can explain how they got to the formula, so I can use in the remaining parts of the project.

Thanks.

(edit: changed the drawing to emphasize the arc is not half the circle)

[image]

Comment: I don't know. But it should be a fixed angle if the radius and a,b are constants, no?

Comment: also if $c$ is simply half the circle, then it's half the circumference which is $2\pi r$. So $c=\pi r$

Comment: Why c would be half of the circle? I didn't say that...

Comment: I was assuming based off of the drawing and cause you didn't specify the start and end of $c$. How far does $c$ go? Where does it start and stop?

Comment: I don't know the start and end of c, that's the point. I goes from the point where the tangent lines touch the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

$$c=(2\pi-4\arctan(a/2r))r$$

Here's why:  If you connect the center of the circle to the two ends of the baseline, you will have four identical right triangles, each with the same angle at the center. If we call this angle $\theta$, then the leftover angle is $2\pi-4\theta$, so that $c=(2\pi-4\theta)r$.  It remains to note that the side opposite $\theta$ has length $a/2$ while the side adjacent has length $r$, so that

$$\tan\theta={a/2\over r}={a\over2r}$$

and thus $\theta=\arctan(a/2r)$.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. After a short struggle with radians vs degrees, I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: @danielv, glad it helped.  As it happens, I was just thinking about adding a remark about making sure you compute the arctangent in radians and not degrees.  Sorry I didn't think of it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $\theta$ is the angle between $b$ and $a$ then $\frac{r}{b}=\tan (\frac{ \theta}{2})$

can you do from this?

---

let $\angle BCB'=\theta$ so that $\angle ACB=\frac{\theta}{2}$. We have:
$$
\angle ABC=\frac{\pi}{2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{BC}}=\tan (\angle ACB)=\tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
$$

and the central angle (the concave angle) that subtend the arc $c=B'B$ is

$B'AB=\alpha=2\pi-2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\pi+\theta$ . And the lenght of the arc is $l=\alpha r$.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more than that? It's been few decades since geometry class :)

Comment: I added a figure . I hope it's useful :)